# Hibernate search: search in composite key EmbeddedId

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have class `CKey` defined as an embedded id class.

I defined class `BEntity` and used a two way string field bridge for the composite primary key.

I difined class `AEntity` with relation `ManyToOne` with `BEntity`.

```
@Entity @Indexed
public class AEntity {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false) @IndexedEmbedded(depth = 1, includeEmbeddedObjectId = true)
    @JoinColumns(value = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_fId", referencedColumnName = "fId"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "fk_sId", referencedColumnName = "sId") }, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_sub"))
    private BEntity bEntity;
}

@Entity @Indexed
public class BEntity {
    @EmbeddedId @IndexedEmbedded @FieldBridge(impl = CompositeIdBridge.class)
    private CKey cKey;
}


@Embeddable @Indexed
public class CKey {
    @Field
    private String fId;
    @Field
    private String sId;
}

public class CompositeIdBridge implements TwoWayStringBridge {
    @Override
    public String objectToString(Object object) {
       return String.format("%s.%s", (CKey) object.getFId(), (CKey) object.getSId());
    }
    @Override
    public Object stringToObject(String stringValue) {
       String[] compositeIdProperties = stringValue.split("\\.");
       return new CKey(compositeIdProperties[1], compositeIdProperties[2]);
    }
}
```

Then, I tried to do a hibernate search on the Entity class `AEntity`, but ran into this exception:

> Unable to find field bEntity.cKey.fId in AEntity

```
Query query = getQuery().bool()
                .must(getQuery().keyword().onField("bEntity.cKey.fId").matching("111111").createQuery())
                .must(getQuery().keyword().onField("bEntity.cKey.sId").matching("222222").createQuery()).createQuery();
FullTextQuery fullTextQuery = getFullTextEntityManager().createFullTextQuery(query, AEntity.class);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `@IndexedEmbedded(depth = 1)` in `AEntity` explicitly requires that only fields up to depth 1 are embedded. `bEntity.cKey` is at depth 1 relative to `bEntity`, but `bEntity.cKey.fId` and `bEntity.cKey.sId` are at depth 2.

Either you should increase the depth:

```java
@Entity @Indexed
public class AEntity {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @IndexedEmbedded(depth = 2, includeEmbeddedObjectId = true)
    @JoinColumns(value = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_fId", referencedColumnName = "fId"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "fk_sId", referencedColumnName = "sId") }, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_sub"))
    private BEntity bEntity;
}
```

... or you should include these field explicitly:

```java
@Entity @Indexed
public class AEntity {
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @IndexedEmbedded(depth = 1, includeEmbeddedObjectId = true,
            includePaths = {"cKey.fId", "cKey.sId"})
    @JoinColumns(value = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_fId", referencedColumnName = "fId"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "fk_sId", referencedColumnName = "sId") }, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_sub"))
    private BEntity bEntity;
}
```

Comment: The error doesn't show anymore when depth is 2. But the query returns null although data exists in the database. The first time when i start the application it returns null, but when i restart the application it returns data.

Comment: I think the problem is in the build of the index. I added this line
. I add this ligne   `fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();` It now works in the first time, but it take a long time to get the data. Is there another solution?

Comment: `fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();` builds the index. Think of it as an equivalent of an SQL script to initialize your database. That's not something you should do for each query. You should only do it once, the first time you start your application. The easiest way to do so is generally to put a button in your administration console.